# Proper way/approach to play an Audio File at Background with main thread or a separate thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, audio, multitasking

I'm bit new to android but I'm good at Java J2SE. I just need to know about the proper or the best way to play an audio file in my android file at the background. According to my knowledge I may have these two options to achieve my objectives:

**1. I may use a runOnUiThread{} to play my background audio file in all the activities of my app in the background, and in the meanwhile I may use another thread or an activity to do my other things done!
 2. The second approach is I must use only a separate thread to play my background audio file!** what should i choose?

---

This is it! It was all according to my knowledge. I mean, may be I'm at the wrong point of me. So, what I need is to know what should be the proper approach/way to play an audio file at the background of an android app in it's all activities(background).

---

The thing is that, actually I am working on a game. I want to play an mp3 file to be played when the app starts and I shall able to do other things while playing. I'm new ro android and need to know about the correct and best way!

---

I will be thankful to you just need the hints and I will do my task done! just want to know how can I achieve this and what should be the best way at all. Again thanks in advance!

Comment: use a service for this purpose. http://javapapers.com/android/how-to-play-audio-in-android/

Comment: can you please explain or give me some link so that I can search it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a separate thread if you need a background music this will be more efficient as to control the multitasking and have proper control on your app. Secondly, you need not to play an audio in

```
  runOnUIThread{}
```

i.e the main thread at all.